# How to dismiss a popup on blur, without a timer, and allow clicking of options within the popup

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a custom select widget in javascript. You all know the functionality, start typing to filter the list options, click an item to select it and click out the box and the drop down will dissapear.

Problem is, javascripts blur or focusout events trigger before the click events for the item im trying to select. The only solution i can possibly think of is to set a timer on the blur function to dimiss the popup after say 200 miliseconds so the click event gets caught in the popup window. this method is literally disgusting and void of all elegance. Does anyone know how native frame works deal with this issue? be it for any popup that dismisses when clicking outside the widget?

Comment: add an event listener to the entire `body`. look for the event target, if its your popup (probably a `div`), handle, if not, remove the handler and dismiss. many samples easy to google, like https://techstacker.com/posts/yz6e9Ksz6ARbNpQAZ/vanilla-javascript-how-to-detect-clicks-outside-of-an

Comment: So what is the code you are using? That would help you in getting an answer.

Comment: it really is a common problem that can be applied anywhere. no code is needed. its as simple as the blur event fires before a click event in a link in a popup, so its tricky getting the popup to dismiss on blur, yet still allowing clicks on the popup to fire (like when selecting an item)

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. But it might be useful to point out that by preventing the click event over the modal from bubbling up the DOM, it's possible to rely on the click event of a parent container to dismiss the modal, rather than on focus events.

Comment: ah true, thanks dlatikay ive actually seen that approach before. I still feel like hopefully theres a more elegant approach but i have a feeling thats the way its achieved

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to have your modal not be a child of the overlay, but a sibling to it. Then clicks in the modal dialogue will not bubble to the click event handler of the overlay.

```js
var trigger = document.getElementById('open_modal');
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
trigger.addEventListener('click', openModal);
overlay.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

function openModal(e){
  overlay.style.display = 'block';
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

function closeModal(e){
  overlay.style.display = 'none';
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
p{
  margin:10px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#overlay{
 display:none;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#modal{
display:none;
position:absolute;
background-color:#fafafa;
border-radius:4px;
width:200px;
height:150px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id='overlay'></div>
<div id='modal'>
  <a href='#'>Click me</a>
</div>
<div id='content'>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus reprehenderit soluta suscipit amet, eveniet natus quod, laborum adipisci molestias minus animi cupiditate eligendi repellendus quidem maiores officia sapiente eius placeat.</p>
<a href='#' id='open_modal'>Open Modal</a>
</div>
```

alternatively you can have a `stopPropagation` on click events inside the modal window.

```js
var trigger = document.getElementById('open_modal');
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
trigger.addEventListener('click', openModal);
overlay.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

//stop click propagation in the modal
modal.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();//this will prevent the events from bubbling out of the modal window to a parent listener.
});

function openModal(e){
  overlay.style.display = 'block';
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

function closeModal(e){
  overlay.style.display = 'none';
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
p{
  margin:10px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#overlay{
 display:none;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#modal{
display:none;
position:absolute;
background-color:#fafafa;
border-radius:4px;
width:200px;
height:150px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id='overlay'>
<div id='modal'>
  <a href='#'>Click me</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id='content'>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus reprehenderit soluta suscipit amet, eveniet natus quod, laborum adipisci molestias minus animi cupiditate eligendi repellendus quidem maiores officia sapiente eius placeat.</p>
<a href='#' id='open_modal'>Open Modal</a>
</div>
```

Comment: ah man this solution is truly beautiful but i dont have an overlay. i wish i did. Thing with an overlay is it allows you to trigger popup close via a click. My trouble is im trying to trigger menu close via blur or focusout, but that always triggers before the click in the modal so its useless thus far. looks like either solution i take from here is gonna feel hacky. its a shame. this is such a common feature thats needed

Comment: @Gravychain I don't know enough about the specifics of your environment to be able to offer a useful solution then, unfortunately. The one thing I could suggest you look into is using the `capture` phase for events. It's a lesser used part of the event scheme, but it lets you listen to events on the way DOWN the DOM tree, and it precedes the standard bubbling phase. There's some info on it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events. hope you find what you're looking for.